# Как мигрировать схему работающей БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, миграция, devops

Есть проект с несколькими серверами, которые используют СУБД MySQL (один экземпляр, но реплики в планах). Как я понял из практического опыта, невозможно изменять схему таблиц, которые используются в данный момент. Однако у серверов постоянное подключение к БД и они блокируют нужную таблицу (видно по полю `In_use` в команде `SHOW OPEN TABLES;`). На данный момент проект в стадии разработки, поэтому для изменения схемы можно спокойно отключить сервера на пару минут. Но как производить обновление схемы на проде без остановки серверов? И нужно ли для этого принимать какие-то меры на этапе разработки?

Comment: ну вообще таблица не должна быть наглухо заблокирована. Если это так значит у вас есть постоянно висящие незавершенные транзакции, чего быть вообще то не должно. alter обычно спокойно можно дать. Другое дело, что он сам эксклюзивно заблочит таблицу на время операции. Для мелких таблиц это не страшно, они быстро изменятся.

Comment: А вот большие таблицы могут меняться часами и все это время приложение не сможет как минимум писать в них. Мы решаем это обычно созданием другой таблицы с новой структурой, включением в приложении режима проведения всех изменяющих данные операций на основной таблице и в новой ее копии (да, у нас предусмотрен такой режим прямо в приложении). И в это время отдельный внешний скрипт переливает старые данные в новую таблицу с игнорированием дублей и небольшими порциями, что бы не перегружать диск. И вот когда он все скопирует то дается краткий лок обоих таблиц и переименование

Comment: В принципе можете посмотреть у percona есть утилиты которые это делают создавая триггера. но везде есть свои подводные камни ...

Comment: @Mike действительно, там была пара зависших транзакций. Если проблема только из-за этого, и в норме схемы табличек редактируются без проблем, то вопрос снимается. Можете написать в формате ответа, я приму `:)`

Comment: Ну вы лучше подумайте сколько данных будет в этих таблицах в проде. А то ведь mysql по любому чиху делает сам копию файла таблицы и переливает его весь, а потом еще индексы перестраивает. И табличка с жалкими 100 млн записей может литься полдня и все это время она не доступна для записи ...

Comment: Где-то на Хабре попадался коммент с рассказом, что в таблицы заранее добавляют несколько запасных столбцов разных типов, чтобы в будущем вместо тяжёлой миграции просто переименовать столбец нужного типа :)

Comment: @andreymal ахах, интересный способ! 

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет про mysql, то можно попробовать

```
mysqldump --no-data dbname > database_schema.sql
```

p.s.: хм.. что-то я сначала не дочитал вопрос, отвлекся. и теперь дал ответ не в полной мере отвечающий вопросу  :) сорри